# Is there any common context for "enoughs"?

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns

I noticed today that ENOUGHS is valid in Scrabble(tm), and I realize "enough" can be used as a noun ("I've had enough!"), but I'm unaware of any context where one might use its plural.  Perhaps it's used in some setting I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Enough*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0267080#m_en_gb0267080) is being used as a pronoun in "I've had enough!" Like other [indefinite pronouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_pronoun) of this kind ([*plenty*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0640150#m_en_gb0640150), [*nothing*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0566340#m_en_gb0566340), etc.), it is usually only used in the singular. ("Enough is enough.")

The only use of *enoughs* that I could find is in [this book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=KqcOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA411&lpg=PA411&dq=%22all+the+enoughs%22&source=bl&ots=h74zqEJTd4&sig=4G1qtYg-23PF7p6TUBA6Cul0DPs&hl=en&ei=DNpwTcC_HIrmrAe6yYjSCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22all%20the%20enoughs%22&f=false). Even here, it is used within quotation marks to show its unusual usage.

> Lerner thinks that this won't work; the connections are too tenuous as all the "enoughs" show.

The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) cites 5 instances of *enoughs* being used. Apart from errors like "Enoughs enough", it has a couple that might work:

> Good enoughs, 40%. Divorce caused tumult but didn't make lasting impression, good or bad... -- *USA Today* (Presumably, this is in explanation to some kind of graph or study.)

> ...if you were nimble enough and canny enough and stubborn enough and enough other enoughs...

Make of that what you will. I'm not sure if this kind of usage qualifies the word's acceptance in Scrabble.

Comment: I think the examples of "enoughs" are all really using "enough" as a word or part of a phrase, and then referring to multiple occurrences of that word or phrase. Almost any word could be used in a plural that way, like "There were ten him's in that paragraph." i.e. not meaning ten men identified. but the word 'him' used ten times.

Answer (score 3):

7th here

http://www.english-test.net/toeic/vocabulary/words/333/toeic-definitions.php

> Definition of enough (noun) form
>   plural: enoughs
>   adequate amount; sufficient degree

Comment: I believe the OP is asking for a situation where one would use the plural form of enough, not whether 'enoughs' is a valid word.

Comment: I know, but first I needed to see it outside a scrabble book

Answer (score 3):

I decided to consult Google and found "close enoughs" and "just enoughs."

These could be used as "There have been too many close enoughs already!"

However, the same phrase more properly written would be "There have been too many 'close enough's already!"

I cannot think of a time where enoughs would be used alone so this is a meager answer at best.